# runtime error 5981 on Office/excel 2010 fresh installation

Tags: excel

I've created macro in excel 2013 where I point some data from excel to Word (via word template).
in excel 2013 everything works perfectly, but now I have to run this excel also in older company PC where is installed only M$ Office 2010/win7 - fresh installation.

```
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(Template:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("O1").Value & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("G2").Value)
```

in this excel 2010 I get run-time error  5981 (application-defined or object-defined error).

in cell "O1" is file folder where are this excel + word templates saved
cell "G2" contain info which template should be used (according to dropdown selection).

update: I've checked this on other PC with office 2010 and it works. Probably some add-in/library  is not working correctly, but idk how to check it.

Comment: ok so I find out, you have to allow changes in word template. if you save template from other source, then you just need to open it, allow changes (in yellow row) and close...and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Error 5981 seems to have two descriptions attached to it (why?):

1. Could not open macro storage
2. Application-defined or object-defined error

Since I got the second description I can only comment on that one, although "Could not open macro storage" seems to suggest that there is something wrong with (the macro's in) the Word file itself.

In my situation the cause of error 5981 was that the Word-template was not a trusted document.
When opening the Word-template manually, it was opened in **protected view**. When opening the template automatically via VBA this apparently results in an error 5981.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because when you open the word template the view is protected.
Solution: disable protected view in microsotf word
Go to options, trusted center, protected view disable